# Invoke AWS Lambda into React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple form executed into React page:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {LambdaClient, InvokeCommand, LogType} from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda"; // ES Modules import
const { fromTemporaryCredentials } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-providers");


const FooterOne = ({ footerLight, style, footerGradient }) => {

  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "YOURKEY",
    secretAccessKey: "YOURSECRET"
  });


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const credentials = await fromTemporaryCredentials({
      params: {
        RoleArn: "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:email-submit",
      },
      clientConfig: {
        region: 'us-west-2',
      },
    })();

    try {
      const client = new LambdaClient({
        region: 'us-west-2',
        credentials,
      });

      const command = new InvokeCommand({
        FunctionName: "email-submit",
        Payload: JSON.stringify("payload"),
        LogType: LogType.Tail,
      });

      const { Payload, LogResult } = await client.send(command);
      const result = Buffer.from(Payload).toString();
      const logs = Buffer.from(LogResult, "base64").toString();
      return { logs, result };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error invoking function:', error);
      // Handle errors as needed
    }
  };

  return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Enter your email'
              name='email'
              required=''
              autoComplete='off'
          />
          <input
              type='submit'
              value='Subscribe'
              data-wait='Please wait...'
          />
        </form>
      </>
  );
};

export default FooterOne;
```

Lambda code into AWS Lambda:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };
  return response;
};
```

Do you know how I can call the AWS Lambda code when I submit this simple form?

Comment: You have all the code there, you just don't know how to invoke it from the form submit. This isn't an AWS Lambda question at all, it's a basic front-end JavaScript question. If you searched for how to call a JavaScript function on a form submit you would have found TONS of examples, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989121/run-javascript-function-on-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

Your code above does not call `handleSubmit()` at all.  Put a `console.log("inside handleSubmit()")` to know when it is being invoked, and also console.log() the result from the `await axios(....)` to know what the response value is (200, 404, 301, 302, 500, ... ???)

If this were me, I would make a few changes to your code above:

```js
import {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const FooterOne = ({ footerLight, style, footerGradient }) => {
  const [emailValue, setEmailValue] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  async function logMovies() {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://i1xsjzkri4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/serverlessAppFunction',
      { email: `${emailValue}` }
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className='newsletter-form position-relative d-block d-lg-flex d-md-flex'>
      <input
        type='text'
        className='input-newsletter form-control me-2'
        placeholder='Enter your email'
        name='email'
        required={true}
        autoComplete='off'
        onChange={setEmailValue}
        value={emailValue}
      />
      <button onClick={logMovies}>
        {loading ? 'Please wait...' : 'Subscribe'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FooterOne;
```

Changes:

- useState to hold `emailValue`
- useState to hold `loading` (indicates if an asynchronous action is happening)
- changed `<form>` to `<div>` -- we want the styling but not the behaviour of a FORM
- text `<input>` shows value of `emailValue` text and calls setEmailValue in the `onChange` event
- changed submit `<input>` to a `<button>`
- text of the button changes based on value of `loading`
- `logMovies` now sets value of `loading`

Comment: I edited it. Can you show me how to invoke the POST request when I click submit button?

Comment: What is calling `logMovies()` ?  Typically you would call that function from an `onClick` event on a `<button>`.  I strongly encourage avoiding use of `<form>` in React since that tag invokes "form submission behavior" in the browser (which people use `.preventDefault()` to avoid)....but you are better to simply take control of the form process in your React code entirely on your own.  Personally I have taken to using `react-hook-form` almost exclusively.

Comment: nothing is calling `logMovies()`. The code is unfinished.

Comment: I updated my answer with changes I would look to make to your original code.  I have not tested the above so there might be a few tweaks that need to be made, but directionally it is what I'd be doing.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use AWS SDK because I don't want to use AWS API Gateway. I want to make a direct lambda call. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779871/call-aws-lambda-function-without-using-api-gateway-and-ec2-instance

Comment: The changes I made above are purely changes for how React works.  If you decide to go after a different URL in your `axios()` call, nothing else would be affected.

Comment: I have added so far basic code with `aws-sdk-js`. Do you know how I implement it properly?

Comment: @Peter - That looks fine at first glance.  Is it working?  If not, what's the behaviour and are there any errors?

Comment: I get `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Credential is missing`

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious...but did you replace the values of `"YOURKEY"` and `"YOURSECRET"` with ... your actual values for the key and secret ?